# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers Error on Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

I have recently downloaded and installed Sitecore' web forms for marketers. It has installed successfully and I have created a Form within the CMS with basic fields on it. However when I go to add the form to a page through PageEditor I get the message "an error occured". When I then check the log I see the following exception

```
Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'System.Guid Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData.get_PageEventDefinitionId()'.
Source: Sitecore.Forms.Core
   at Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.CustomizeAnalyticsWizard.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

I have decompiled the Sitecore.Analytics DLL and I cannot find this method that it is looking for anywhere. I downloaded the module version 2.5 for SItecore 7.5 revision 150209.

Can anyone tell me if I am missing a newer or older version of the a DLL or something because I can't seem to figure out where this method should exist.

Thanks

Comment: OK further to this I have installeed Sitecore8 and found that the member PageEventDefinitionId exists in the Sitecore 8 version of the Analytics DLL. I am not quite sure how to proceed with this now. Do I need to install an earlier version of the WFFM module or do I need to update the version of the Sitecore Analytics DLL which I can see causing all sorts of problems. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you do have a version mismatch, with the WFFM version you are using. Which version did you download?

Comment: I Downloaded version 2.5 revision 150209 which states on the sdn that it is for Sitecore 7.5. I have downloaded another revision which I am now going to try.

Answer (score 2):

OK after a bit of looking around and tweaking. I stripped out the version I installed by following the documentation on how to uninstall WFFM. I then downloaded **version 2.5 revision 141014** and installed that. At a first glance this seems to be working. If I add the form to the page via content editor it works and renders fine. It seems to submit fine too. The forms won't render using page editor mind but I am not sure what that issue is as I haven't investigated.

Either way it would seem that revision 150209 is for Sitecore 8 and revision 141014 is for Sitecore 7.5. Hope this helps anyone else who comes across the same issue.